# Proving composition of two functions $f\circ \gamma$ having a limit implies $f$ has a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity, proof-explanation

> **Problem Statement:** Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be open, and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Assume that for any continuous curve $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow U$ with $\gamma(0)=x_{0}\in U$, we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} f(\gamma(t))=L\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} f(x_{k})=L$.

I am not quite sure how to approach this proof. I thought that if I can show that $f$ is continuous in $U$, then that would be enough to finish the proof, but I feel that we do not have enough information about $f$ to show it is continuous in $U$.

My professor gave us a hint that it is enough to show that for any sequence $\left\{x_{k}\right\}\in U$ with $\lim x_{k}=x_{0}$, then $f(x_{k})\rightarrow L$.

I think it makes sense to me why this should be true, but the only thing that I feel is the missing piece is that we don't know if $f$ is continuous in $U$.

Is this the correct strategy? Any suggestions on how to approach this problem are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to show that $f$ is continuous in all of $U$ (which is a lot to ask of $f$), but your professor's hint can be quite useful.

You want to show that for any sequence $\{x_k\}$ of points in $U$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k=x_0$ we have $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k)= L$.  It would be nice if we had a continuous path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to U$ so that $\gamma(0)=x_0$ and so that we could choose a sequence of values $\{t_k\}$ which decrease to $0$ so that $\gamma(t_k)=x_k$.  Then we could use the fact that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(\gamma(t)) = L
\end{equation}
to show that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k)=L$.  Consider letting
\begin{equation}
t_k = 2^{1-k},
\end{equation}
setting $\gamma(t_k)=x_k$, and letting $\gamma$ follow any continuous path in $U$ from $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$ as $t$ varies from $t_k$ to $t_{k+1}$. (**Edit:** For sufficiently large $K$, all the points $x_k$ with $k\geq K$ will be contained in some convex neighborhood $V\subset U$, so that the path from $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$ can be chosen to be a line segment.  This will avoid the problems mentioned by zhw in the comments.)  This will define $\gamma$ on $(0,1]$, and then you'll need to show that if we set $\gamma(0)=x_0$, $\gamma$ is indeed a continuous path.

Comment: You've been too generous with $\gamma.$ Better to let $\gamma $ be the line segment from $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$ for large $k.$

Comment: For large enough $k$, sure.  But we can't be sure that $U$ is convex, so not every line segment from $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$ will necessarily be contained within $U$.  I'm curious, though: what's the advantage of using line segments instead of an arbitrary continuous path contained in $U$?

Comment: Suppose we're in $\mathbb R,$ $U = (-2,2),$ $x_0 = 0.$ Let $x_k = 1/k.$ Connect $1/k$ to $1/(k+1)$ by a path that travels from $1/k$ to $1$ and then down to $1/(k+1).$ You keep doing that and the path will not approach $0.$

Comment: Ah, good point. Thanks for catching that!